# How do I retrieve a value from a Key with 2 words react

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am building a react application that gets data from Firestore. I am stuck with getting values from a Key: value pair in which the key is more than one word.

I create my component like so:

```
const MyComponent = ({theData}) => {
return (
    <div>
      <p>theData.name</p>
      <p>theData.Special Pass</p>
    </div>
)
}
```

The first one with the "Name" works fine and I can view the value. I am stuck on the second one. I have tried:

```
theData.["Special Pass"}
theData.{"Special Pass"}
```

and several other variations without success. Please assist.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `theData["Special Pass"]`

Comment: Worked for me. Bless you

Answer (score 1):

```
const MyComponent = ({theData}) => {
return (
    <div>
        <p>{theData.name}</p>
        <p>{theData["Special Pass"]}</p>
    </div>
) }
```